# how to design database for country wide data?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, data-modeling, database-partitioning

I have to design a data structure according to states in a country.
The country has more than 30 states and each state would be writing and reading data from its own state. The problem is that whether I should have a partitioned table which will be partitioned by the state_code or make different tables for each state? I am using PostgreSQL. I don't have experience with partitioned tables. There would be huge amounts of data for each state.

The data will be spatial data of each district, sub-districts, villages and schools in those villages.

It will also have data of each child present in each school. This will be the basic information of the child.

Each child will be screened and based on around 30-40 parameters each student will be categorized into the class of problem he is facing.

Data related to health problems of each student will also be there. This will include behavior problems and physical health problems as well.

The health teams visiting the schools will also be stored. For example, members of the team and their information.

I guess now things are more clear. Each state will have more than 1 million rows.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - as it stands, we have not got enough information to answer your question. What data will you store? What do you mean by "huge"? What sort of queries do you anticipate?

Comment: It's impossible to answer the question as it is. The most important factor is: what kind of data you are storing and what is the goal? Every data model serves some purpose. There are **no** universal solutions. Also what does "huge" mean? And what is the expected traffic? The amount itself doesn't mean anything. For example you can have terabytes of logs. So what if you are not going to query them? There are lots of details missing in your question.

Comment: To add to @freakish 's comment also modern RDBMS which includes PostgreSQL are designed to handle huge amounts off data .. The so called "big data" i see the big data term volume wise as handling data which does not fit in the computer memory.. So 9 Gb of data can be "big data" if you only have 8Gb of computer memory..There are more definitions when data can get the label "big data" but everybody seams to have different definitions or opinions when data is called "big data"

Comment: I am editing the question.

Comment: "*More than 30 states with more than 1 million rows*" - that boils down to 30 million or maybe 100 million rows. That isn't considered "huge" these days. And even with 100 million rows you don't necessarily need partitioning to make fast queries. Just create a properly normalized model that efficiently supports the queries you want to run and make sure you create the right indexes to support those. Only **if** you really hit a performance problem think about things like partitioning and/or de-normalizing.

Comment: Ok I’ll try that...and see how it goes!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partitioning by state would be a good idea if you are expecting queries that run sequential scans on the data — if there is a `WHERE` condition that restricts the query to one partition, it would become faster due to PostgreSQL's *constraint exclusion* feature.

If you want to manage users and security inside the database, you could use [row level security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) to guarantee that nobody sees data from a different state. This works nicely with constraint exclusion.

Comment: That’s what I was thinking...so if I partition it by state Id...each partition would be treated as a separate table while reading and writing? If concurrent writing takes place then what happens?

Comment: And yes there would be a where condition always...since one state user won’t be looking at other states data

Comment: Each partition *is* a separate table. Parallel inserts to  single table are not slower than to many tables, so partitioning won't buy you anything there.

Comment: I could do one thing...have it as one table for now...and later if required...make a new partitioned table and migrate the data...thanks for your answer...I get the solution.

Comment: Partitioning later and moving all these rows around would be painful and probably require down time.

Comment: My first idea was that to partition the table...but as suggested here by some people...I considered not to partition it...but yeah u are right...moving data is not easy and involves risks.